# Showing that the sequence $n(\arctan n - \dfrac{\pi}{2})$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\left(\arctan n - \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) = -1$, without using L'Hopital's Rule. Using the fact that
$$\arctan\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(1/\theta)$$
We have that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\left(\arctan n - \dfrac{\pi}{2}\right) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} n\left(-\arctan 1/n\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} -n\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k(1/n)^{2k+1}}{2k+1} $$ $$=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} -\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\cdot (1/n)^{-1}(1/n)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}\cdot (1/n)^{2k}}{2k+1}$$
Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: bound it by a dominating function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $n\arctan(\frac{1}{n})$ is a difference quotient. Namely :

$$n\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=\frac{\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-\arctan(0)}{\frac{1}{n}-0}\to \arctan'(0)=\frac{1}{1+0^2}=1$$

Comment: I like this one. It's like my A but simpler.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the fact that this limit is same as $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}-x \arctan \left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$, then we can use the fact that **tangent function is continuous**. In other words, we can use substitution $x=\dfrac{1}{tan(u)}$ and u goes to $0+$ as x goes to $\infty$. So this limit changes to $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0+}-\dfrac{u}{tan(u)}=-1$

Answer (score 1):

$$n(-\pi/2 +\arctan n)= n \arctan (1/n)= n\int_0^{1/n}\frac {1}{1+x^2}dx \in\left[\frac {1}{1+1/n^2},1\right]$$ because $x\in [0,1/n]\implies \frac {1}{1+x^2}\in [\frac {1}{1+1/n^2},1]$